# Queuing threads in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

my app wants to update pictures on the web on a regular basis. This doesn't require UI feedback, so I just start a new Thread and let it run. The problem is, that this update-method may be called before the previous one has been finished. How can I make sure that the second call doesn't start a new thread but is queued and automatically started when the previous one finished? Are handlers the right solution here as well?

Here the code:

```
public static void updatePictureOnPicasa(final PictureEntry pe) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                if(pe.isUpdated())
                    picasa.updatePicture(pe.getUrl(), pe.getDescription(), pe
                        .getTags());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(Prototype.TAG, "Unable to update picture on Picasa "
                        + pe.getUrl());
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a service feature in Android.Please refer these links:
http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/34861.aspx
http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a promising solution.